# Angular2 material pass mat-select as model on submit

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to pass the model of the form onSubmit and one of the elements of the model is a select option.
How can I pass both the value and selectionName onSubmit?

**Html:**

```
<form #EditUserForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(EditUserForm)">

 <mat-form-field class="container">
    <mat-select [value]="currentUserRole.RoleId" name="RoleId" required >
      <mat-option  *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role.RoleId">{{role.RoleName}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

**Typescript:**

```
onSubmit(EditUserFormModel: NgForm) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two-way binding

```
 <mat-select [(value)]="currentUserRole.RoleId" name="RoleId" required >
```

but this can cause issues in some scenarios, so I would use `ngModel`

```
   <mat-select [(ngModel)]="currentUserRole.RoleId" name="RoleId" required >
```

this way `currentUserRole.RoleId` will be set to whatever user selects in selection box right away.

If you would like to delay binding (eg. in order to create "reset" feature) you will either have to copy first, or better use `ReactiveForms` for that.

Comment: both [(value)]="currentUserRole.RoleId" and  [(ngModel)]="currentUserRole.RoleId" won't even populate the selection only [value]="currentUserRole.RoleId" works ... But it won't pass the value on submit and I also need the selection name  - currentUserRole.RoleName

Comment: okay I found why [(ngModel)]="currentUserRole.RoleId" didn't work - there was a mistake in type - I had currentUserRole.RoleName of type **number** instead of **string**. After I changed it to string it started to bind currentUserRole.RoleId correctly - now I can pass the value this way. But can I somehow also pass RoleName (that is the name of the selection) ? Or that should be done in typescript by fetching RoleName by id ?

Comment: You can pass whole `role` as select value if you need to. Object can be value of input if required.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by

`value and selectionName`

I am guessing the value is currentUserRole.RoleId and the selectionName is role.RoleName

In that case

`[value]="currentUserRole.RoleId">`

The value input specifies the value returned. If both your value and the selectionName are in the currentUserRoleobject, you can just pass this along instead of only the Id to be written to the form fields value.

`[value]="currentUserRole">`

But this also means you would have to change the displayed customise the displayed text. [You can customize this with `mat-select-trigger`](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#customizing-the-trigger-label)

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [value]="currentUserRole.RoleId" name="RoleId" required>
    <mat-select-trigger>
      {{currentUserRole.RoleName}}
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role.RoleId">{{role.RoleName}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

If you are looking for a callback to set the form values [have a look at the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api)

There is an event selectionChange and a property selected which let you hook into the selected option.

If you want to grab a value from outside of the object which select iterates over you probably want to do that in selectionChange and patch your form object.

HTML

```
<mat-select 
  [value]="currentUserRole.RoleId" 
  (selectionChange)="setValues($event, EditUserForm)"
  name="RoleId" 
  required 
  > 
      <mat-option  
          *ngFor="let role of roles" 
          [value]="role.RoleId">
            {{role.RoleName}}
      </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

TS

```
public setValues(event, form): void {
  form.patchValue({...})
}
```

Here you can set values as you wish.

On submit you ideally just pass EditUserFormModel.value to get to your form data.

Sounds kinda like you want to grab values in your onSubmit which I would not encourage. Instead model your form to output all the values you need on submit and just handle the submit itself there. If necessary hook into callbacks to patch values on events.